# Problems with WPF application on Windows XP Tablet having memory leaks

Tags: wpf, tablet

I am testing an application that was developed in C#, .Net 3.5 SP 1, and WPF.  It runs just fine on all kinds of hardware running XP.  Including really old 386's with little memory and slow hard drives.   However, we are having problems with Windows XP Tablet PC Edition 2005 SP 2.   We are seeing what looks like a memory leak, which we have not seen on any other system.  As we click on various GUI items and run the application through it paces, the memory keep growing and growing.  After a certain point ( ~145 MB), the interface becomes almost unresponsive.  I have tried forcing the GC to collect on a regular bases, with no change in behavior.

Has anyone experienced a similar issue.

Answer (score 1):

Are you using Bitmap Effects... I've had problems with them not being released and cause my applications to leak?